How to Optimize Bulk Phone Number Validation Using Google's Phone Library in C#
I'm working on a feature that allows users to import a CSV file containing 100,000 rows with 5 columns. One of the columns contains phone numbers that need to be validated before storing them in a database. I'm using Google's phone library for validation, but it's taking a considerable amount of time in my opinion: 1 minute and 4 seconds.
My laptop that I am testing this on has following specs:
intel core i5 10th gen CPU @ 1.60GHz   2.11 GHz
16 gb ram
Here's the current implementation of my validation function:
public Task<(string, string, string, string, bool)> ValidatePhoneNumber(string PhoneNumber)
        {
            string phoneNumberNationalFormat = "";
            string phoneNumberInternationalFormat = "";
            string countryCode = "";
            bool isValid = false;
            string pattern = "[^0-9+]|(?<=^\\+.*)(?=\\+)";
 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber))
            {
                try
                {
                    var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
 
                    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, pattern, "");
                    var ph = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(PhoneNumber, "US");
                    isValid = phoneNumberUtil.IsValidNumber(ph);
                    countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.GetRegionCodeForNumber(ph);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber))
                    {
                        countryCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode) ? countryCode : "US";
                    }
                    phoneNumberNationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
                    phoneNumberInternationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    PhoneNumber = "";
                }
            }
 
 
            return Task.FromResult((PhoneNumber, phoneNumberNationalFormat, phoneNumberInternationalFormat, countryCode, isValid));
        }

To process all phone numbers, I call this function for each phone number in the CSV file. However, this approach is slow for 100,000 records.
Is there a more efficient way to validate a large number of phone numbers? Are there any best practices for bulk (phone number) validation that I might be missing?

Just to start with: var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance(); is this guaranteed to give you a singleton instance? I'd just pass the (reference to the) util as an argument. You surely don't want to create a new instance for each call.

You are right but I think the main bottlenecks might be the regular expression operations, no?

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber)) is checked twice of which the innermore is superfluent.

"You are right but I think the main bottlenecks might be the regular expression operations, no?" - that would need to be found out by profiling it. I'd just start with the obvious ones you can mitigate..

Have you profiled this to see where it's spending its time? If not, we're just guessing here.

try/catch is expensive. Do you really need it? Why do you return Task from a completely synchronous method? That pattern string can be const - right? And the Regex can be Source Generated....

I'd set up a banchmark(dotnet) and start making candidate improvements. Then measure and over and over ... some things may be more impactful as you think, other quite the opposite.

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber)) by the time you check this the first time, you already have made some allocations. I'd even suggest to actually filter out these outside of the method and make it part of its input-requirements / prerequisites that phone number must be not null-or-empty.

I'd also set the default country code outside of the method. Maybe as part of the db-insert.

Ok I'll profile and get back to you.

Have you considered using Plinq (parallel linq)? That can vastly improve performance for use cases like this. Following is a draft implementation.
First, you'll want to import the libraries that will allow you to use linq/plinq:
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...
Next you can create a pattern like below, where work is added to a concurrent collection then divvied up to be processed by separate threads.
First, imaging you have a method that grabs the big list of phone numbers:
  private static List<string> GetBigPhoneList()
  { 
      // your code here to retrieve the big list of phone numbers...
  }

Here is where the magic happens. At the end of this process, you will get back a collection with all of the phones processed.
public static async Task<ConcurrentQueue<string>> ProcessPhonesAsync<T>()
 {
     var result = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
     var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
     int WorkerCount = 8; // how many cores you want to throw at the problem

     // Declare the worker
     Action<string> work = stage =>
     {
         result.Enqueue(stage);
     };

     // perform the long-running task
     await Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         List<string> Phones = GetBigPhoneList();

         foreach (string PhoneNumber in Phones)
         {
             // your long-running process

             /**
              *  string phoneNumberNationalFormat = "";
                 string phoneNumberInternationalFormat = "";
                 string countryCode = "";
                 bool isValid = false;
                 string pattern = "[^0-9+]|(?<=^\\+.*)(?=\\+)";

                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber))
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();

                         PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, pattern, "");
                         var ph = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(PhoneNumber, "US");
                         isValid = phoneNumberUtil.IsValidNumber(ph);
                         countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.GetRegionCodeForNumber(ph);
                         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber))
                         {
                             countryCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode) ? countryCode : "US";
                         }
                         phoneNumberNationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
                         phoneNumberInternationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
                     }
                     catch (Exception e)
                     {
                         PhoneNumber = "";
                     }
                 }
              **/

             blockingCollection.Add(PhoneNumber);
         }

         blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
     });

     // Start consuming
     blockingCollection
         .GetConsumingEnumerable()
         .AsParallel()
         .WithDegreeOfParallelism(WorkerCount)
         .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
         .ForAll(work);

     return result;
 }


You could try this below code which use the Parallel.ForEach:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.PhoneNumbers;

public class PhoneNumberValidator
{
    private static readonly Regex phoneNumberRegex = new Regex("[^0-9+]|(?<=^\\+.*)(?=\\+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static readonly PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();

    public async Task<(string, string, string, string, bool)> ValidatePhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string phoneNumberNationalFormat = "";
            string phoneNumberInternationalFormat = "";
            string countryCode = "";
            bool isValid = false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
            {
                try
                {
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumberRegex.Replace(phoneNumber, "");
                    var ph = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(phoneNumber, "US");
                    isValid = phoneNumberUtil.IsValidNumber(ph);
                    countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.GetRegionCodeForNumber(ph) ?? "US";
                    phoneNumberNationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
                    phoneNumberInternationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(ph, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    phoneNumber = "";
                }
            }

            return (phoneNumber, phoneNumberNationalFormat, phoneNumberInternationalFormat, countryCode, isValid);
        });
    }

    public async Task<List<(string, string, string, string, bool)>> ValidatePhoneNumbersParallelAsync(List<string> phoneNumbers)
    {
        var results = new List<(string, string, string, string, bool)>();
        Parallel.ForEach(phoneNumbers, (phoneNumber) =>
        {
            var result = ValidatePhoneNumberAsync(phoneNumber).Result;
            lock (results)
            {
                results.Add(result);
            }
        });

        return results;
    }
}

use this class to process the csv file:
public async Task ProcessPhoneNumbersAsync(string filePath)
{
    var phoneNumbers = await ReadPhoneNumbersFromCsvAsync(filePath);
    var validator = new PhoneNumberValidator();

    var validatedPhoneNumbers = await validator.ValidatePhoneNumbersParallelAsync(phoneNumbers);

    // Handle the validated phone numbers (e.g., store them in a database)
}

public async Task<List<string>> ReadPhoneNumbersFromCsvAsync(string filePath)
{
    var phoneNumbers = new List<string>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            var values = line.Split(',');
            phoneNumbers.Add(values[1]); 
        }
    }

    return phoneNumbers;
}

